# Array no almacena el valor completo de mi DB si tiene un espacio

Tags: php, html, mariadb

Dentro de mi DB tengo la siguiente información:

```
MariaDB [agenda]> select * from materia;
+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| idmateria | materia                              |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|         1 | Matemáticas                          |
|         2 | Física                               |
|         3 | Química                              |
|         4 | Ética y Valores                      |
|         5 | Introducción a las ciencias sociales |
|         6 | Taller de lectura y redacción        |
|         7 | Inglés                               |
|         8 | Informática                          |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [agenda]> SHOW CREATE TABLE materia;
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| materia | CREATE TABLE `materia` (
  `idmateria` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `materia` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmateria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci |
+---------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Realicé una conexión a mi DB con un query para cargar los registros. El archivo lo tengo separado de mi código principal:

```
    <?php 

try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=agenda;charset=utf8','root','');
    /*echo "Conexion OK"."<br />";*/
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
}

$asignaturas = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM materia');

?>
```

En esta sección de código donde traigo la información de una DB para llenar un `select` para después de enviar la información a otra página.

```
<?php 

require_once('fn/conexion.php');

$semanas = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
$temas = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
$propositos = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
$recursos = ['1','2','3','4','5'];

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Agenda</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "Agenda_W3.php" method="post">
<hr>
        <p>Selecciona que materia quieres trabajar:
            <select name="materia" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                <?php 
                    foreach ($asignaturas as $asignatura) {
                    echo "<option value=".$asignatura['idmateria'].">".$asignatura['materia']."</option>";
                    }
                 ?>
            </select>
        </p>
```

Agregando `var_dump`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Agenda</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "Agenda_W3.php" method="post">
<hr>
        <p>Selecciona que materia quieres trabajar:
            <select name="materia" id="">
                <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
                object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(21) "SELECT * FROM materia"
}
<option value=1>Matemáticas</option><option value=2>Física</option><option value=3>Química</option><option value=4>Ética y Valores</option><option value=5>Introducción a las ciencias sociales</option><option value=6>Taller de lectura y redacción</option><option value=7>Inglés</option><option value=8>Informática</option>array(4) {
  ["idmateria"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [0]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["materia"]=>
  string(12) "Informática"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "Informática"
}
object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(21) "SELECT * FROM materia"
}
            </select>
        </p>
```

Pero al imprimir el array me doy cuenta que no se almacena el nombre completo del registro, si existe un espacio solo muestra la primera palabra.

```
<?php 
    require_once('fn/conexion.php');
    var_dump($_POST);
        echo '<hr>';

    $bloques = ['I','II','III','IV','V','VI','VII','VIII','IX','X','XI','XII','XIII'];

    /*Almacena el digito en una variable para usarse en un ciclo*/
    $asignatura = $_POST['materia'];
    $no_proposito = $_POST['no_proposito'];
    $no_tema1 = $_POST['no_tema1'];
    $no_recurso1 = $_POST['no_recursos1'];
    $no_tema2 = $_POST['no_tema2'];
    $no_recurso2 = $_POST['no_recursos2'];
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Agenda W3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="w3-container agenda">
        <p>Agenda para la materia: <?php echo $asignatura;?> </p>
        <form action="genera_html.php" method="post" target="_blank">
            <div class="w3-row w3-round bloque">
                <div class="w3-col w3-container ">
```

¿Qué ocasiona esto y como puedo solucionarlo? Tal vez lo estoy haciendo mal, pero debería de almacenar en el array el registro completo, en este caso la palabra "Ética y Valores"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon el código completo. Es muy extraño lo que te está ocurriendo, también todo lo que pasas al crear la instancia PDO.

Comment: @A.Cedano Listo agregué la segunda sección de mi código donde imprimo la variable.

Comment: Pon todo, también el código completo de la instancia PDO que estás creando.   Y la imagen que muestras supongo que es un `var_dump`... pon también ese código y donde sacas el `var_dump`. Incluso si tienes código CSS que afecte a los datos, convendría que lo pongas. Es muy extraño. Yo trataría de ver también un `SHOW CREATE TABLE materia`. No sea que haya alguna restricción a nivel de tabla.

Comment: @A.Cedano actualicé la información.

Comment: Pues muy raro e intrigante tu caso. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($asignaturas);` antes del `foreach`?  ¿No tendrás una tabla bis o una base de datos bis que sea la que estás consultando por error?

Comment: Listo, agregué `var_dump` pero tuve que _Ver el código fuente_ para poder verlo, porque el `for` lo uso en el index.

Comment: El `var_dump` sólo muestra una materia que es `Informática`... no muestra más materias. Tampoco comprendo bien cómo tienes organizado tu código, veo que tienes un `var_dump` del POST por otro lado. ¿La imagen que se ve es el var_dump  del `$_POST`? ¿Cómo usas `$asignaturas` en el  `select ... option`, o sea, usas archivos distintos, cómo la pasas al archivo HTML?

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo mi código en un [repositorio] (https://github.com/MarcosRugerio/Agenda). Tal vez te sea más sencillo visualizar mi código.

Comment: En la imagen muestro un `var_dump` y justo es del `$_POST`.  Asignaturas es una variable donde almaceno el query `SELECT * FROM materia` después lo mando a llamar para cargar las materias que tengo dentro de la DB y poder meterlas dentro de la etiqueta `<select>` por cada valor que tenga en la DB me imprime un `<option>`.

Comment: Bueno lo voy a revisar, pero dime el orden lógico que sigues, porque de lo contrario me puedo pasar una hora o más tratando de armar la lógica del código. Y dime si usas Ajax para esto (sería lo mejor) y creo que el verdadero problema es alguna confusión en el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano No uso Ajax, pero estaba revisando esa parte de Ajax visto que se pueden crear formularios dinámicos.

Comment: Sí, debes considerar el uso de Ajax. Pero centrándonos en el problema, necesito conocer cómo funciona el código. Por ejemplo, si recoges datos de un formulario, los mandas al servidor, que hace la consulta y te devuelve (o debería devolver las materias). ¿Cómo estás haciendo eso y cómo lo estás depurando? ¿Cómo estás recogiendo de vuelta la respuesta del servidor con (supuestamente las materias traídas de la base de datos) para presentarlas en la página? En el código no se ve con claridad como haces todo ese proceso.

Comment: Si justo veía que con el Ajax podría ahorrarme algo de código tal vez quitar el index y entrar directo a trabajar en `Agenda_w3.php`.  Estoy describiendo mi programa "chafita" ejejeje.

Comment: A mi me gusta usar el estilo `MVC`: de Modelo-Vista-Controlador. Permite mantener el código organizado y es mucho mejor de mantener, actualizar. Aparte de que te ahorras una barbaridad en el código. En ese caso `index.php` puede hacer de **Controlador** para redirigir todas las peticiones (imaginando que tu aplicación podría crecer en un futuro, incorporando además de una `agenda`, también un `calendario` o un block de `notas`). El `index.php`  serviría para recibir las peticiones que se harían, además a través de URL *elegantes*  tipo: `www.dominio.com/agenda`  o `www.dominio.com/calendario`

Comment: Cuando se escriba `agenda` en la URL, el controlador (`index.php`)  invocaría al **Modelo** `Agenda`, que puede ser una clase que además haga uso de una clase auxiliar de conexión a la base de datos. El modelo `Agenda` consulta a la base de datos, extrae los datos que se le piden y los pasa a la **Vista**, que es el único organismo encargado de imprimir cosas en tu aplicación. La Vista puede usar plantillas, tener método para salida de tipo JSON, XML, HTML, etc. Eso permite tener un código ordenado, claro y muy fácil de mantener o de depurar en caso de error.

Comment: Suena algo complicado el `MVC`, estoy regresando a esto de la programación nunca lo ejercí pero estudiaré Ajax para mejorar e implementarlo para mejorar mi código; revise un poco y parece JavaScript.

Comment: @A.Cedano encontré mi error, omití las dobles comillas del tag <option value=""></option>. Al final las agregué y las escape. Gracias por tu apoyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución a mi problema, el detalle esta en las comillas `" "` del `<option value>`, olvidé agregar las comillas del tag `<option value=""></option>` y además escapar el caracter para que se almacene el valor.

*Código original:*

```
<?php 
    foreach ($asignaturas as $asignatura) {
        echo "<option value=".$asignatura['materia'].">".$asignatura['materia']."</option>";
    }
 ?>
```

*Código escapando las comillas y escapandolas*

```
<?php 
    foreach ($asignaturas as $asignatura) {
        echo "<option value=\"".$asignatura['materia']."\">".$asignatura['materia']."</option>";
    }
 ?>
```

Al escapar las comillas el valor es guardado en el array sin problemas.

```
array(8) {
  ["materia"]=>
  string(37) "Introducción a las ciencias sociales"
  ["semana"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["no_proposito"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["no_tema1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["no_recursos1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["no_tema2"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["no_recursos2"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(6) "Enviar"
}
```